# How to tell which Kendo grid action has fired datasource changed event?

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI jquery grid with an event handler bound to the datasource change event.  I need to reload the data only if the action is paging or sorting, not grouping.  Is there any way with the event arguments to tell what action  triggered the event?

Comment: I can't see anything using the dataSource event but the grid has its own page, sort, group events https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events.  I would try binding to the grid's page and sort events to do what you want...although paging and sorting kind of "reload the data" anyway so I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Indeed you are correct.  I didn't realise there were specific events I could hook into, some other older telerik page said there was only a data source changed event.  The main issue with Telerik is they have been around for a long time and their online doco is so fragmented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything using the dataSource event but the grid has its own page, sort, group events docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events. I would try binding to the grid's page and sort events to do what you want...although paging and sorting kind of "reload the data" anyway so I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. – The Dread Pirate Stephen Jun 26 at 11:24